# Chrome cross-origin blocked

Tags: google-chrome, nginx, cookies, cross-domain, samesite

I got a problem with cors get-request.

A external Website (iframe on my website) triggers with button click a certain URL in my CMS like "dev.my domain.com/index.php?id=123". Its a GET request.

The problem is that I got an nginx error 500 in all Chromium browsers like Chrome, opera and so on . If I run this URL "dev.my domain.com/index.php?id=123" straight on my server without a referer (without using that iframe button) its working (code 200).

In Firefox there is no problem at all. Is this a more a browser or server (nginx) problem and how can I fix this? I tried things like:

```
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
add_header Referrer-Policy 'no-referrer';
```

But nothing hepled.

[image]

Comment: When you check the server logs on the `dev.domain.de` server, what messages is the server logging about whatever internal server failure is happening that causes it to respond with that 500 error?

Comment: Strange thing is, there is no error in any logs. There is only in the access_ssl_log this:  `GET /index.php?city=Uelzen&cl=hermes&name=Autohaus%20Brandt&shopid=669736&street=Hansestr.%2022&zip=29525 HTTP/1.0" 500 1710 "https://paketshop.myhermes.de/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.90 Safari/537.36`

Comment: Ok what I found out, its a browser thing. All Chromium powered browsers have sameSite:latex by default. https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592

Comment: Quick update: It was a cookie problem. All Chromium based browsers require the SameSite attribute with a value of "None" for cross-site cookies. So: SameSite:None for your cross-site request cookies.